# URL rewriting not working with ASP.NET MVC IIS 7.0 Windows Server 2008 64bit

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I Installed ARR Version 2 and Enabled proxy settings (64 bit version). I created a rewrite rule as below. It will rewrite only if it meets specific condition. Its an ASP.NET MVC application.(both current and rewritten applications)

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> 
    </modules> 
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="input=2" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="SomeOtherDomainURL/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule> 
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

With above configuration rewrite is not working.
When I set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = "false"`, its working, but current ASP.NET MVC application is not working, it needs managed handler to run.

When I set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = "true"`, rewrite is not working at all, but current ASP.NET MVC application works.

How to achieve both only through web.config changes?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do with the rewrite rule?

Comment: Redirect to somewhere else if the query string contains input=2? I have the exact same issue.